# How to recreate \newenvironment and \newcommand with \NewDocumentEnvironment and \NewDocumentCommand in LaTeX3

Tags: macros, environments, expl3, xparse

In order to learn better about handling dynamic arguments and "blocks" like what you pass to a command/environment, I would like to try to write a wrapper function around `\NewDocumentEnvironment` and `\NewDocumentCommand` that does pretty much exactly what they do. However I would like the API to be:

```
\myenvironment{foo}{<args>}{startblock}{endblock}
\mycommand{foo}{<args>}{block}
```

i.e. even though the API is `\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}` with the backslash `\foo`, I would like to make it `foo`.

Here is the MWE for the system:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{mmm} {
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{#2}{#3}
}

\mycommand{myenvironment}{mmmO{}} {
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
}

\myenvironment{foo}{m}{
  \typeout{#1}
}{}

\begin{foo}{abc}

\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

The things I am not sure about are:

1. Passing through the arguments like `\NewDocumentEnvironment{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}`
2. Handling "blocks", since all I've ever dealt with in passing arguments is simple one-liners/strings/key-val pairs.
3. How to handle the `foo` to `\foo` transformation when passing through.

Wondering how to get this to work using the above definitions for `\myenvironment` and `\mycommand`:

```
\begin{foo}{abc}

\end{foo}
```

Comment: I doubt that you get much with this 'chain' loading here. And you don't need `\ExplSyntaxOn` if you're using `xparse` macros alone

Comment: There are a lot of spurious spaces in your macros which are just not notified because of using `\ExplSyntaxOn`.

Comment: Off-Topic: You have asked a lot of questions in the meantime, and some of them have answers, but are not accepted. Please go through your list of questions and consider to accept the answers

Comment: @ChristianHupfer will do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid doing general definitions inside `document`. And remember to issue `\ExplSyntaxOff` when you're done with the code part.

You *could* make `\NewDocumentCommand` to accept a string instead of a control sequence. The question is: why? It just obfuscates code, generally speaking.

Anyway, `\exp_args:Nc` is the construct to use. It tells LaTeX to build a control sequence from the braced argument following the next token and then it disappears. It's the same, in “oldstyle” TeX programming as

```
\expandafter\token\csname string\endcsname
```

Note also that your `\myenvironment` has an *optional* final argument, so it should be given in brackets `[]` rather than in braces `{}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{m +m +m}
 {
  \exp_args:Nc \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{#2}{#3}
 }

\mycommand{myenvironment}{m +m +m +O{}}
 {
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\myenvironment{foo}{m}
 {%
  \typeout{#1}%
 }

\mycommand{baz}{m}{X#1X}

\begin{document}

\baz{Y}

\begin{foo}{abc}
Something inside
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess I need to learn the meaning of "control sequence", don't understand that one yet.

Comment: @LancePollard `\section` is a control sequence, `foo` isn't.

Comment: Was looking how to do this with LaTeX3 features, thanks for pointing out the `\exp_args:Nc` and `\expandafter\token\csname string\endcsname` equivalence.

Comment: @LancePollard `expl3` and `xparse` are meant to provide _consistent_ interfaces for programming. Stretching them like doing `\mycommand` isn't good for users.

Comment: actually this doesn't work, getting `! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{thebibliography}` if changing to `\myenvironment{foo}{m}{\begin{thebibliography}{9}}{\end{thebibliography}}`. This does work however: `\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname}{#2}{#3}` not sure why latex3 way doesn't.

Comment: @LancePollard With your code you should have `\myenvironment{foo}{m}{\begin{thebibliography}{#1}}[\end{thebibliography}]` as you declare the fourth argument as `O{}`

Comment: The second and third argument of `\mycommand` should be long, though, same for `myenvironment`, the last three arguments should be long (and I just see that my answer from back then doesn't define the second argument long, so I'm wrong, too).

Comment: @Skillmon Point taken!

Answer (score 5):

I don't see the point why you would want to tokenize the arguments, just to pass them on.  Instead, just [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) the `\NewDocumentCommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\mycommand[1]{\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\myenvironment{\NewDocumentEnvironment}

\begin{document}

\mycommand{hello}{}{world}

\hello

\myenvironment{foo}{m}{
  \typeout{#1}
}{}

\begin{foo}{abc}

\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Didn't realize you could do this, thanks!

Comment: Wondering how you knew to do the `\expandafter`.

Comment: @LancePollard Actually this partial macro application (also called currying) is an often overlooked technique which can make a lot of macro code much simpler.  Perhaps I'll write a TUGboat article on this and other functional programming techniques TeX.

Comment: Yes please, do it!

Answer (score 3):

The `\mycommand` macro should be defined as

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{mm+m} {%
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
}
```

since the `#1` must become the argument name, so the typical `\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1\endcsname`.

The 3rd. argument 'must' be `+m` in order to allow for the definition code of `\foo`, which is more likely to contain just more than one paragraph.

The same is true for the 3rd and 4th argument of `\myenvironment`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}


\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{mm+m} {%
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
}

\mycommand{myenvironment}{mm+m+O{}} {%
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
}

\myenvironment{foo}{m}{%
  \typeout{#1}
}{}

\begin{foo}{abc}

\end{foo}

\mycommand{foobar}{om}{%
  \IfValueT{#1}{Yes, there is an opt. argument: #1}

  Mandatory Argument: #2

}

\foobar{Hello World}

\foobar[And now for something completely different]{Hello World}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Skillmon: I am not finished yet and the `\myenvironment` code is not changed from the O.P. (yet)

Comment: Wondering how you knew to do the `\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1\endcsname` , I have not seen that before. I am new to "expansion", haven't used it yet at all.

Comment: @LancePollard: If you would have asked 5 years ago I would not have known about `\expandafter`. And I could not have answered your question. You have to construct the command sequence name (note, the name, not the command sequence definition!), i.e. `\foo` first, before `\NewDocumentCommand` can grab this name and define it as a sequence, so you have to 'jump' over `\NewDocumentCommand` with `\expandafter`, letting `\csname ...\endcsname` come into action, this marks a valid command sequence name then and `\NewDocumentCommand` does the rest. The same would be true for `\newcommand`, anyway

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{ m +m +m } {
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname}{#2}{#3}
}

\mycommand{myenvironment} { m +m +m +m } {
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
}

\myenvironment{foo}{ m }{
  \typeout{#1}
}{}

\begin{document}


\begin{foo}{abc}

\end{foo}

\end{document}
```